I want to hardcode a location into an android app by modifying it, but it crashes when i do so
There is this app that checks if you are at a certain spot before letting you scan a qr code. I want to skip the location check by modyfying the system calls for location and hardcoding a set of coordinates but when i do so it crashes as soon as i click scan qr.
I changed this
invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/location/Location;->getLongitude()D  move-result-wide v1
to this
const-wide/high16 v1, 0xc0531f9e
and the same for latitude.

What is the crash? Please share the stacktrace and the relevant code

Sorry just saw your comment, i am a noob at these did it all by asking chatgpt so i didn't know i needed to stacktrace, all i can find on the internet is how to do it in android studio but i'm compling and decompling it using java on termux and doing it all on android so i don't know how can i stacktrace

You said there is a crash. If one does happen, you should see the crash logs in logcat when running through Android Studio.

I will be doing that as soon as i get access to a PC
